# Changing order of Integration with constant limits

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a double integral as follows $$\int_{0}^{L}\int_{0}^{t}f(x,\tau)d\tau dx$$ 
Since the limits are constants, I change the order of integration as follows $$\int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{L}f(x,\tau)dx d\tau$$

Is this the right way or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: You need either integrability(Fubini) or positivity (Tonelli).